# Migrating ASP.NET 2005 to 2008 issue with crystal report reference

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, web-config

The ASP.NET website was developed using VS.NET 2005 version and used Crystal Reports.
Now the same wants to upgrade to VS.NET 2008, but it is showing errors like below:

> Error 469 Could not load file or assembly
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.  C:\Documents
>   and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\SVSS\ssvs10022010123\Web.Config    29

In the web.config file, the code is written like where this error refers to.

```
<compilation debug="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Framework, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoStore, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
```

Crystal Reports is already installed (which comes by default with VS2008). Do we need to change the reference?
Please guide me on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Check here to download the necessary files http://hellowahab.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-crystaldecisions-enterprise-framework-version10-2-3600-0-cultureneutral-publickeytoken692fbea5521e1304-or-one-of-its-dependencies/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, the crystal report version is changed in .NET 2008.

You should replace your old version string with new version like this
Version=10.2.3600.0  to Version=10.5.3700.0

Alternate solution to find the exact version of Crystal report in your system is,

Right click on Project folder and choose reference. Now select all the crystal reports references and press Ok.
It should automatically update the web.config file with correct version. (You can delete the old crystal report reference code in web.config).

Comment: I copied data from an old machine to new machine and got the same error. I installed Crystal Reports runtime and changed the version. It still gives the same error with the new version number. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Best solution is installing same runtime on the server.
Anyway, you can use this XML in your app.config or web.config:

```
  <runtime> 
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="xx.x.xxxx.x" newVersion="yy.y.yyyy.y"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.Shared" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="xx.x.xxxx.x" newVersion="yy.y.yyyy.y"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource" publicKeyToken="692fbea5521e1304" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="xx.x.xxxx.x" newVersion="yy.y.yyyy.y"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        ...
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

where **oldVersion** is the version you use for development and  **newVersion** is the version installed on the server

Comment: Couldn't this also be fixed by setting "Specific version" to false for those references?

Comment: I have now, and it doesn't. Will use this for now, will rebuild later using @Ajay's solution. Thanks.

Comment: I copied data from an old machine to new machine and got the same error. I installed Crystal Reports runtime and changed the version. It still gives the same error with the new version number. Any help is appreciated